# Python truncating slice assignment

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am wondering why Python truncates the numbers to integers whenever I assign floating point numbers to a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.asarray(list(range(10)))

print ("lst before assignment: ", lst)
lst[:4] = [0.3, 0.5, 10.6, 0.2];
print ("lst after assignment: ", lst)
```

output:

```
lst before assignment:  [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
lst after assignment:  [ 0  0 10  0  4  5  6  7  8  9]
```

Why does it do this? Since you do not need to specify types in the language, I cannot understand why numpy would cast the `float`s to `int`s before assigning to the array (which contains integers).

Comment: This behavior doesn't apply to primitive lists.

Comment: You initialize your lst as ints, then `dtype` didn't change and fractional part is truncated.

Comment: @erip you are right, just checked the code I tested the primitive list with. Made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is clear once `numpy.asarray`'s signature is seen:

```
numpy.asarray(a, dtype=None, order=None)
```

If `dtype` isn't set, it is inferred by the data provided. In your case, it was `int`s.

You could make your example work if you set `dtype=np.float32`:

```
import numpy as np

lst = np.asarray(list(range(10)), dtype=np.float32)

print "lst before assignment: ", lst
lst[:4] = [0.3, 0.5, 10.6, 0.2];
print "lst after assignment: ", lst
```

> lst before assignment:  [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
>
> lst after assignment:  [  0.30000001   0.5         10.60000038   0.2          4.           5.           6.
>      7.           8.           9.        ]

For more information, you can find the docs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html#numpy-asarray).

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In oposition to python's native lists, numpy arrary's are typed. Even though this might be counterintuitive in a dynamically typed language like python, it stems from the fact that numpy is basically a python wrapper arround highly optimized ` code.

You can change the datatype of a numpy array by passing the desired datatype in the `dtype` keyword argument to the numpy.array constructor:

```
 numpy.array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order=None, subok=False, ndmin=0)
```

> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array. For downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

[numpy constructor](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

[dtype values](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Comment: Note that OP was asking about `numpy.asarray`. Your answer is still good and makes the point, but it's a little different.